# How can you create a chrome notification that contains custom HTML?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

In a chrome extension, I would like to make a chrome notification that has a form with a few custom HTML elements, like

- 2 questions that each have a five-star rating scale (a bunch of buttons)
- a textbox to enter text

Looking at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications, I see that webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification() is deprecated in favor of https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.

However, this new format doesn't have options for using custom HTML to design the notification. Among other limitations, there can only be 2 buttons at most.

Is there a way to create a custom HTML form in a chrome notification so that there can be more buttons + more custom design?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. With `createHTMLNotification` gone that's the only thing you can do (a couple of buttons).

You could always create a new popup-type window with `chrome.windows`, but that's not the same thing.